# UTF-8 and JTextArea

Tags: java

i have 2 JTextArea that one of these contain Unicode Code point like this \u0645 i want another JTextArea

show Character representation of this Unicode code point.but when pass this code point to JTextArea , it show

code point not Character but if i set code point to JTextArea setText method directly it work correctly !

why ? and which can i pass String of Codepoint from one JTextArea to another ?

thanks

Comment: How exactly do you transfer the text from one JTextArea to the other when you get the wrong result?

Comment: Also please note that the issue at hand has **nothing** to do with UTF-8!

Answer (score 2):

This code displays a character, and in the other text-area the corresponding "unicode string" counterpart:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
        Container cp = jf.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        JTextArea ta2 = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        Character c = '\u0645';
        ta1.setText("" + c);
        String s = String.format("\\%04x", (int) c.charValue());
        ta2.setText(s);
        cp.add(ta1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cp.add(ta2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(500, 100);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

So if you have a long text of such characters, you would need to **loop through the string character by character**, (using `getCharAt(int)` or `getChars()`) and process each character with `String.format("\\%04x", (int) c.charValue());` and append the result to the target string. (Preferrably using a `StringBuffer`.)

Comment: hi,i have String of Codepoint for example : "\u0645\u0645" this don't work with your solution.

Comment: Then iterate through the string using `getCharAt` or `getChars`.

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextArea text=new JTextArea();

String dir=text.getText();

JTextArea text2=new  JTextArea();

text2.setText(dir);
```

but this don't work, dir contain string of code points.if i pass String of codepoint directly to

setText("\u0645\u0645") it's work !

Comment: That would be better suited as an edit to your question, not as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

> If i set code point to JTextArea setText method directly it work correctly !

If by this you mean something like `myTextArea.setText('\u0645')`, then the issue is rather clear:

The **Java compiler** interprets `\u` as the beginning of a [unicode escape](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#100850). That means that *anyhwere in Java source code* the characters `\u0645` are completely equivalent to actually putting the character `م` (Unicode character [U+0645 ARABIC LETTER MEEM](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0645/index.htm)) at that same place.

So the following two lines do exactly the same thing:

```
myTextArea.setText('\u0645')
myTextArea.setText('م')
```

The reason for this is, because *at compile time* `\u0645` is turned into the corresponding Unicode character.

It's an entirely different situation if you have the Java String that contains the 6 characters `\u0645`. That String can be represented as the Java String literal `"\\u0645"` (note the double-backslash to avoid the compiler interpreting the Unicode escape).

In that case you can grab the third to last character (`"\\u0645".subString(2)`), parse that as a hexadecimal number (with `Integer.parseInt(theString, 16)`) and cast the result to `char`. Then you'll have a `char` value containing the actual Unicode character.